# Is there a way to react to a hibernate native query

Tags: spring, hibernate, nativequery

I am working on a webapplication with Spring and Hibernate. In a certain situation I want to revoke the user's write access to the database. Therefore I have implemented `EventListeners` that react to the Events I am interested in.
The application however also uses some `NativeQueries` that seem to be ignored by the `Listeners` and any `Interceptor` I could think of.

I'm using Spring 3.0.5 and hibernate 3.6.8.

Is there a way to react to these native queries without implementing my own `NativeQuery` class (and `EntityManager` and god knows how many classes I would need to get the whole thing to work again)?

Comment: Although this question is old, I'd try posting an idea here. Isn't easier and safer to revoke the INSERT and UPDATE rights of the user by running a native query? So something like this: REVOKE INSERT ON *.* FROM 'jeffrey'@'localhost'; whenever an Event you're interested in appears?